# Postgresql \i permission denied

Tags: postgresql

Hello I've been trying to run a script on postgresql and the message im getting is:

```
dellestore=# \i /Users/tbd/Desktop/dellestore2-normal.sql

/Users/tbd/Desktop/dellestore2-normal.sql: Permission denied
```

I'm just learning postgresql,
I'm working on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: try running it with sudo

Comment: `chmod a+r /Users/tbd/Desktop/dellestore2-normal.sql`?